# POSTGRES WINDOWS "server not listening" (beginner)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

When logging to PGadmin and trying to access my databases (linked to a Rails app) I get an error such as 'server not listening'.
My password doesn't work

Yet when unsinstalled and reinstalled Postgres it works all fine again

It happend to me already and same as above solved the problem

Can someone points what setup is lost at some point (when restarting Windows?) that a new installation reinstates ?

Comment: Did you try some `pg_ctl` [commands](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pg-ctl.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably have to start the service each time you need it:

On Windows XP, if you were logged in as a user with administrative rights, you could simply run cmd to start what in the old days we used to call a "DOS box" and run something like this:

```
NET START postgresql

NET STOP postgresql
```

http://1stopit.blogspot.com.ar/2011/10/how-to-start-and-stop-postgresql-on.html

Comment: Tried that but had an Error 5. Your link has helped much here. So the service was probably down. I should be able to restart the service next time. Many thanks